# xyz coordinates from reprojectImageTo3D opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, stereo-3d

OpenCV's reprojectImageTo3D is supposed to provide xyz coordinates from a disparity image and a Q projection matrix.  It returns a 3-channel unsigned char image, _3dImage. Each element of _3dImage(x,y) contains 3D coordinates of the point (x,y) computed from the disparity map.  How is one supposed to access the xyz coordinates from the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[oh, wait](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void%20cvReprojectImageTo3D%28const%20CvArr%2a%20disparityImage,%20CvArr%2a%20_3dImage,%20const%20CvMat%2a%20Q,%20int%20handleMissingValues%29), it's not a 3-channel unsigned char image, but a 3-channel *float* image

```
Point3f p = _3dImage.at<Point3f>(row,col);
// p.x
// p.y
// p.z
```